# Touch sensing in SK game not sensing touchesEnded

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

**UPDATE:**  per request I have NSLogged `[[event touchesForView:self.view] count]` and `touches count` and got output of `2` and `1` when the glitch occurs, so it appears that the event is being lost somehow?

Here's my two simple methods: (updated)

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];


        if (touchLocation.x < self.size.width / 2.0f) {
            NSLog(@"left");
            touching = YES;
        }

        if (touchLocation.x > self.size.width / 2.0f) {
            NSLog(@"right");
            if (![rocketFlame parent]) {
                [self fireRocket];
            }
        }
    }  
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
        for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    NSLog([[event touchesForView:self.view] count]);
    NSLog([touches count]);


        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];

        if (touchLocation.x < self.size.width / 2.0f) {
            NSLog(@"left off");
            touching = NO;
        }

        if (touchLocation.x > self.size.width / 2.0f) {
            NSLog(@"right off");
            //do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, I'm getting a bug where the game doesn't sense an ended touch on the left side of the screen. I'm not sure if this bug may also affect the right side of the screen, since that action is only run once and isn't a continuous action so I wouldn't notice if it didn't sense the ended touch.

Basically, if I touch simultaneously and end my touches simultaneously, it will run `fireRocket` and change `touching`  to `YES` but then never changes `touching` back to `NO` even though both fingers are lifted off.

Here's the log output:

```
right
left
2
1
right off
```

Comment: Can you add the code where register those gestures?

Comment: @jhk there.. isn't any? I didn't know I needed to do that?

Comment: the touchesBegan method has always worked without any additional code

Comment: I wanted to see if you were doing anything strange with cancelsTouchesInView, delaysTouchesBegan, or delaysTouchesEnded properties. I believe what is happening is that the event is getting merged into one gesture. In the touchesEnded method try NSLogging  [[event touchesForView:self] count], [touches count] and even the touch.tapCount within the for loop.

Comment: @jhk I NSLogged the first two things you asked me to and I got interesting results. [[event touchesForView:self] count] returned 2, and one line later, [touches count]  returned 1.

Comment: My main suspicion is that once there are two touches, it merges into one event. So when the last finger is removed it calls the touchesEnd callback method. What happens when you put two finger down and lift off the right side one first and then lift the second (left) finger off? I am hoping it's something like `right, left, 2, 1, left off`.

Answer (score 2):

My main suspicion is that once there are two touches, it merges into one event. So when the last finger is removed it calls the touchesEnd callback method.

There are couple ways to handle your solution.

**First** one is in `touchesEnd` see if `[[event touchesForView:self.view] count]` returns a number greater than 1. Once it's greater than two, loop through `[event touchesForView:self.view]` and make sure it meets your "right" and "left" criteria.

**Second** option is to have additional boolean variables that gets set to `YES` inside `touchesBegan` but only when you have both left and right registered. I am thinking something like "leftTouched" and "rightTouched". And inside the `touchesEnd` method just see if that variables are set to `YES`. Remember to add code to reset it to `NO` at the end of `touchesEnd` method.